# Wrap a span around some text in jQuery

Tags: jquery

What I have :

```
<ul id="myId">
    <li>
        My text
        <ul class="myClass">
            <li>blahblahblah</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

What I want :

```
<ul id="myId">
    <li>
        <span>My text</span>
        <ul class="myClass">
            <li>blahblahblah</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I dont have access to the HTML markup, and am wanting to do this with jQuery, 
Something like :

```
$('.myClass').get_the_text_ubove().wrap('<span>');
```

There must be some way of selecting 'My text' even though it has no class/id

Comment: Are you looking to add the class `myClass` as well, or should that also exist in the "what you have" section?

Comment: Nope, sorry my bad, updated question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
$('#myId > li').each(
    function(){
        $(this.firstChild).wrap('<span></span>');
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/mmMXD/).

With regards to wanting to add the `class` to the `ul`:

```
$('#myId > li').each(
    function(){
        $(this.firstChild).wrap('<span></span>');
        $(this).find('ul').addClass('myClass');
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/mmMXD/1/).

Comment: Thanks, Im going to keep your answer, Its clean and simple.

Answer (score 6):

```
$($('#myId ul').addClass('myClass')[0].previousSibling).wrap('<span>');
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Qxkba/1/)**

Comment: Your answer was close enough, sorry for forgetting 'myClass' in my question, I have updated the question

Answer (score 3):

```
var ul = document.getElementById("myId");
var li = ul.firstElementChild;
var text = li.firstChild;
var ul = li.childNodes[1];
ul.classList.add('myClass');
var span = document.createElement("span");
span.textContent = text.data;
li.replaceChild(span, text);
```

Old fashioned DOM to the rescue.

Comment: +1 That was going to be my next task (but don't forget to add the class, like I did at first).

Comment: [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qxkba/2/) Oops, I screwed it up and added the class to the wrong element!

Comment: @RightSaidFred you added the className to the wrong ul ;) [Fixed](http://jsfiddle.net/Qxkba/3/)

Comment: [Here's a fun way](http://jsfiddle.net/Qxkba/6/) to write it for those who like chaining.

Comment: @RightSaidFred by fun you mean bleed my eyes. If I have to maintain code like that, I will rage quit

Comment: Well, as long as it's your eyes and not mine... ;) I'd probably rather spread it out a bit [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/Qxkba/8/). This to me is just beautiful code. :)